# Date variable in local storage doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sharepoint

I have some code that sends data with different types to local storage. However, some of them is "undefined" and that is only a issue with IE11.

```
public getEvents(): Promise<IEventItem[]> {  
    return new Promise<IEventItem[]>(( resolve) => {  

    //get the items that I want to store 

       sp.web.getList(window.location.pathname + '/Lists/Events').renderListDataAsStream(this.getParams()).then((streamitems) => {
            const _items: IEventItem[] = [];

           streamitems.Row.map((elem) => {

                _items.push({  
                    Title: elem.Title,  
                    Date: new Date(elem.EventDate), //undefined
                    EndDate: new Date(elem.EndDate), //undefined
                    Category: elem.Category,
                    Location: elem.Location,
                    ID: elem.ID,
                    IsCached: false,

                });
                window.localStorage.setItem(this.cacheKey, JSON.stringify(_items));
            });


            resolve(_items);
        });
    });
}
```

See above code with the comments. If I instead do

```
Date: elem.EventDate
```

I get a value, but I get other issues instead, and need to create a new Date class. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar issues on IE in the past.
Can you try:

```
Date: moment(elem.EventDate).toDate()
```